# Is it possible for the PHP function uniqid() to generate the same name twice?

Tags: php, function

I have been using the function uniqid(), but I'm thinking, is it possible for the PHP function `uniqid()` to generate the same random name twice?

The answer that I see everywhere is no, but why? why isn't it possible to generate a name that was generated before by kind of mistake. I mean it probably could generate a name that was generated before, even if it was set to true like this => `uniqid('', true)`, it may generate the same name by coincidence?

Comment: rtm: *read the red box* https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Yes, it is possible to generate a random ID twice. See the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#:~:text=Warning)'s warning. They're not cryptographically secure either.

Answer (score 1):

> Warning
> This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value. Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to increase likelihood of uniqueness.

— https://www.php.net/uniqid

Answer (score 0):

My answer it is possible, but not practical.

Much like the no two snowflakes are alike statement, it might happen, but the odds of anyone noticing are seriously small?

When you look at the odds, we are talking about being struck by lightning while standing under a metal shelter on a sunny day type of odds.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

If you want to do the math feel free.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are dealing with the "rather extreme edge-case" of two-or-more threads possibly calling this function simultaneously within the same microsecond .... I would say that "your fears are comfortably unfounded."